# Matplotlib doesn't show last figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to show figures but when it comes to the last figure, it doesn't show its content (just creates the window). 
I use it to depicture maximal independent sets of a graph. So, sets is actually a list which contains lists of nodes.

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes

for i in range(0, len(sets)):

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, sets[i],
        node_color='r', node_size=500,  alpha=0.8)

    rest = []
    for j in nodes:
            if j not in sets[i]:
                rest.append(j)

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, rest,
        node_color='w', node_size=500,  alpha=0.8)

    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=1.0,alpha=0.5)


    plt.axis('off')
    plt.figure(i)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you move `plt.show()` into the loop do you still see the same thing?

Comment: It has a very strange behavior. It shows two windows for each loop, one of which is empty, and the other one is the correct. Another problem is that it waits for me to close them, before it proceeds and shows the next ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes

for i in range(0, len(sets)):

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, sets[i],
    node_color='r', node_size=500,  alpha=0.8)

    rest = []
    for j in nodes:
            if j not in sets[i]:
                rest.append(j)

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, rest,
        node_color='w', node_size=500,  alpha=0.8)

    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,width=1.0,alpha=0.5)


    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show(block=False)
```

Move `plt.show()` into the loop and remove `plt.figure(i)`
Then you won't see empty plots and you don't need to close plots manually.

Comment: This actually works, but I have to close a window in order to show me the next one. I think it's fine. Thank you

Comment: If you think it's helpful please accpet this answer. Appreciated!